# When does the js engine insert semicolons?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

I know you can chain js (or jquery) on differnt lines like so:

```
$('div')
    .filter(':first').hide().end()
    .find('span').css('opacity', .5)
    ...;
```

And the engine doesn't put semicolons in which would break it. On the other hand if I do this:

```
return
    i ? 1 : 2
```

It puts a semicolon in and always return undefined. What are the guidelines for when it does what?

Comment: The JavaScript parser will only place semi-colons if it encounters an error...

Comment: If you want a _really_ general guideline, it would be "Never put a linebreak between the `return` keyword and the expression being returned. For non-return statements don't worry." Yes this is oversimplifying things, but it will cover you almost all of the time.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Good point. I guess I use `throw` so rarely in JS that I didn't think of it. (But then I did say I was giving a _really_ general oversimplified guideline, so...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the subsequent lines are invalid syntax when used alone.

In your second example, the second line is a valid (though useless) statement.

For more precise rules, see the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.9), which goes on for three pages.

Comment: The moral of the story: use semicolons.

Comment: @SLaks: Two people have downvoted it, and I can only speak for one of them. The reason that *I* downvoted it is that, despite being the "accepted" answer, it's completely wrong. (Well, technically, each of the first two paragraphs makes a correct statement; but their purpose is to imply something that is completely wrong.) Something like `+ 1;` is a valid statement, but `return 1 ((newline)) + 1;` will *not* trigger semicolon insertion; it is equivalent to `return 1 + 1;`, but if your comment were correct, it would be equivalent to `return 1; + 1;`.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ: That's a pretty useless moral, since the chief problem with semicolon insertion is that it happens even if you use semicolons everywhere that you should. (Not as often as SLaks's answer implies, but still.) The real moral is that, as "C++ Pitfalls" puts it, "Even language features that you never use can bite you!" (http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/pitfalls.html) Or, alternatively, that language designers shouldn't design languages to insert semicolons. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: It looks like Javascript adds semi-colons at new lines wherever it could make sense. Your first example would not be valid javascript if the second line began with '.' so it assumes it is one line, whereas in your second example, each line could potentially be valid js. For example:

```
return
1 + 2;
```

returns undefined, while both:

```
return 1 +
2;
```

and

```
return 1
+ 2;
```

return 3 because at least one line does not make valid js.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug.  It is the stupidest feature in any widely-used programming language.

Comment: Watch some Crockford. He uses that example a lot `:)`

Comment: Wow, and all this time I had no idea.

Comment: @Godwin If you put a line break between `return` and the expression, the JavaScript parser will put a semicolon after `return` - this is the reason why `undefined` is returned in your demos. This is not a bug, it is defined in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation at [http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons](http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons). Quoting from it:

> 3. When a "restricted production" is encountered and contains a line terminator in a place where the grammar contains the annotation "[no LineTerminator here]", then a semicolon is inserted.
>
> [...]
>
> Restricted productions are those in which a line break cannot appear in a particular position, so if a line break appears there, it will prevent the program from parsing in that way, though it may still parse another way.
>
> There are five restricted productions in the grammar, they are the postfix operators `++` and `--`, continue statements, break statements, return statements, and throw statements.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that return statements can contain linebreaks within the expression, just not between the `return` token and the start of the expression.

In other words, `return ...` is a specific construct wherein, if you put a line-break after the `return`, JavaScript will insert a semicolon. There are several other such constructs as well; but aside from these, JavaScript will only ever insert a semicolon if there's no way to make sense of your code without one.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why?

Comment: (Actually, @downvoter, never mind: everyone else, except for Mario, gave a completely wrong answer. I assume you're simply under the same misapprehension.)

Comment: Strange how the worst answers get all the upvotes and are picked as the correct one, when the topic is about Javascripting. The quality of programmers, sadly, has really degraded in the web-development job, mostly thanks to jQuery coders I guess.

Comment: @Mario: I'd prefer to think that this specific error is a common misconception among JavaScripters, rather than that JavaScripterkind is going to Hell in a handbasket. This confusion is an understandable one, certainly. (And it's mostly harmless, when you think about it. The worst that can happen, if you believe that JavaScript inserts semicolons at every line-break where it can, is that you'll defend against it even in cases where you don't need to. Slightly uglier/less-idiomatic code, maybe a few more bugs as a result . . . but I've seen much worse confusions than this.)

Comment: @Mario: For what it's worth, I've upvoted your answer. It's still at -2, but at least your net reputation from it is positive. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is better described as ending the statement parsing than inserting semicolons. In JS, semicolons are purely decorative.

The parser stops when it has a complete statement. The behaviour with return is exactly what you should expect, since return without an argument is a legal statement. It seems to be the only case that might get you into trouble if you're not careful because JS can't read your mind.

Putting the return argument on a separate line would be pathological even if it parsed right.

Comment: This is not true. If it stopped when it has a complete statement, it would stop at `$('div')`. As other answers have noted, it also needs to consider the next line.